# Print to MATLAB command window from mex file and another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, matlab, printf, mex

I modified a sample program to demonstrate the issue: It prints a string each second.
The problem is that the messages appear in the command window after MATLAB returns to idle state (all at once).
If it is called from the command line and MATLAB returns to idle, the messages appear in the command window:

```
mexFile;
```

But in this case:

```
mexFile; while 1; end;
```

The messages appear after I abort the endless loop by ^C.

Here is my source code. It uses `feval("fprintf"...)`. A subsequent call to `pause(0.001)` or `drawnow` does not change anything.

How can I force matlab to "flush" messages to the command window?

```
#include "mex.hpp"
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"
#include <thread>
#include <future>    


class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<matlab::engine::MATLABEngine> matlabPtr = getEngine();
public:
    void print(const std::string& msg)
    {
        matlab::data::ArrayFactory factory;
        // Pass stream content to MATLAB fprintf function
        matlabPtr->fevalAsync(u"fprintf", 0,
            std::vector<matlab::data::Array>({ factory.createScalar(msg) }));
        // matlabPtr->evalAsync(u"pause(0.001);");
    }

    void DisplayDateTime() {
        matlab::data::ArrayFactory factory;
        for (int count = 0; count < 20; count++)
        {
            print("Loop " + std::to_string(count) + "\n");
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }

    void operator()(matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs,
        matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs) {
        mexLock();
        voidStdFuture = std::async(std::launch::async,
            &MexFunction::DisplayDateTime, this);
    }
};
```

Comment: [This](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/making-async-requests-using-mexcallmatlab.html) seems to me to indicate that the async call is supposed to happen after the MEX-file finishes. Are you running your MEX-file out of process? If not, the MATLAB process freezes until the MEX-file finishes. Maybe calling `drawnow` after printing helps?

Comment: Have you tried `feval`? Not sure, but it seems from what you write in the other question that things have changed a lot wrt the old C API.

Comment: @CrisLuengo If you call feval from a separate thread, matlab will crash. If you call feval from the main thread, the messages appear even if matlab is busy. And no, drawnow does not change anything.

Comment: `fevalAsync` can write to a user provided [stream buffer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.engine.streambuffer.html).
So it appears that you need to define a sub class of [std::basic_streambuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) that wraps the stream buffer of `std::wcout`. MATALAB needs a stream buffer of type `basic_streambuf<char16_t>` while `wcout` has a stream buffer of type `basic_streambuf<wchar_t>`. That should be considered when overriding the virtual methods. Those methods properly call the methods of the wrapped stream buffer.